# Retaining "0" in .csv Format

Tags: excel-2003, export-to-csv

I had converted .xls file to .csv format. I had done this by opened the Excel and done Save as to csv format. The .xls file has values like '00116','0860371' etc. But once converted to .csv, its not retaining the "0" and the value is like '116','860371' etc.

I had changed the format to "Text" and tried..But its not retaining the "0"

How to Fix this....

Comment: renaming the file format is not right way. Open the xls file and save as csv file.

Comment: sorry..i had done like that only....

Comment: this gives error when u have multiple sheets in a xls file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you open the csv file in excel, it trims all the preceding zeros. Better open in other text editors.

Comment: I want to fill my datatable with that .csv file data..So for that, the data in the file should be retained with "0"

Comment: @RobinHood then convert the particular cell datatype to text.

Comment: @Jameelopix "then convert the particular cell datatype to text." ... when importing using the import wizard. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to duplicate this issue.

In Excel 2003, I enter `'00116` in cell A1 and `'0860371` in cell B1.

I go to the Save As dialog and choose "CSV" for the type. When I click "Save" it asks me to confirm. I click **Yes**. I close Excel and click **No** when it asks if I want to save changes to the CSV file.

I browse to the saved CSV, right click and choose **Edit** (to open the file in Notepad). The file contents are:

`00116,0860371`

In order to open this file in Excel without losing the leading zeroes, I:

- Start Excel again and go to Data » Import External Data » Import Data.
- Browse to the file and click **Open**.
- In step 1 of the import dialog, choose "Delimited" and click Next.
- In step 2, select "Comma" as the delimiter and click Next.
- In step 3, I set both columns to **Text** and click Finish.

Click OK and both values are imported, with leading zeroes intact. The leading apostrophes are dropped.